# how to tell if filter() returns a new list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When scraping this [Afghanistan page](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/afghanistan/), I got an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "extract_table.py", line 23, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                    
    li = dict(chunks([i.text for i in all_td], 2))                                                                                                                                                                 
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #28 has length 1; 2 is required
```

But when scraping [Argentina page](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/argentina/), code runs fine.

Is there any way on how to tell that if `all_td` has returned a new list?  I'd like to know what functions in python to use.

something like this pseudocode:

```
if all_td is new list,
    execute dict(chunks([i.text for i in all_td], 2))
else
    execute dict(chunks([i.text for i in areatable.findAll('td')], 2))
```

What I want to accomplish is to run the code to both countries afghanistan and argentina.

This is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                                                                       
import urllib2                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import re                                                                                                                                                                                                           

url = "http://www.howtocallabroad.com/afghanistan" # argentina works fine
html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

areatable = soup.find('table',{'id':'codes'})
if areatable is None:
    print "areatable is None"
else:
    d = {}

    def chunks(l, n):
            return [l[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]


    all_td = areatable.findAll('td')
    all_td = filter(lambda x: x.attrs == {}, all_td)
    print ">>>>> all_td=", all_td

    li = dict(chunks([i.text for i in all_td], 2))
    print ">>>>> li=", li
```

Answer (score 2):

Your filter is eliminating these 3 names because `.attrs != {}`

```
    <tr>
      <td width="25%">Badghis</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td width="25%">Kabul</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td width="25%">Panjshar</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
```

This is why you're getting an odd number to chunk up into pairs. And the result would be mangling numbers to unrelated names even if it ended up having an even number.

Argentina works fine because they don't have the extra width attributes in there.

This is a pain because now you *know* they're not just populating those tables from a template like any sane person would. Someone is hand fiddling at least some of them.

You'll have to code much more defensively when trying to parse those types of pages.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, `filter` not returning a list is not the source of your problems (apart from the fact, that it may be filtering out items you don't want to be filtered out), but a bug in your `chunks` function. The `dict` constructor takes  an iterable of iterables of *length 2*. Your function `chunks` doesn't always return pairs (if the list has odd number of items).

---

*Example:*

```
In [1]: def chunks(l, n):
   ...:     return [l[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

In [2]: a = chunks(range(4), 2)  # even number of elements

In [3]: b = chunks(range(5), 2)  # odd number of elements

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [[0, 1], [2, 3]]

In [5]: b
Out[5]: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4]]  # <-- note the trailing [4] at position 2

In [6]: dict(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-57f7c289a3e5> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(b)

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 1; 2 is required
```